# mysql last_inset_id is not returning the nextval of primarykey

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

i am using spring jdbctemplate for inserting rows into mysql database, i am facing problem  while doing batch insert into mysql database. issue is, when inserting the second row, i am getting duplicate key violation on my primary key. i have placed the USER_KEY inside the batch update method, but i am getting exception `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`, while inserting the second row.

my method is not annotated `@Transactional`.

Note:- i need to generated primary key through code and have this for update/delete actions, so not relying on auto_increment. in addition jdbctemplate batch insert will not return the generated key though.

here is my code

```
    private static final String USER_KEY = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM USER";


jd.batchUpdate(INSERT_QUERY,
                    new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                        @Override
                        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int count)
                                throws SQLException {
                             Long userId= jd.queryForObject(
                                        USER_KEY, Long.class);
                            UserDO Userdo = userlst
                                    .get(count);
                            ps.setLong(1, userId+1);
                            ps.setString(2, Userdo .getFirstName());
                            ps.setString(3, Userdo .getLastName());
                            ps.setString(4, Userdo .getMobile());
                            ps.setString(5, Userdo .getEmail());
                            ps.setInt(6, 0);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int getBatchSize() {
                            return UserdoLst.size();
                        }
                    });
```

appreciate your valuable answers. Thanks

Comment: if it is autoincrement key why cant you just don't use the field in insert statement?

Comment: i need to have id value in my code, as i said i need to have id value for update data, so cant user autoincrement function

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` as the name says returns the `ID`(if any) of the last inserted record. You actually read this back from the database right after the insert. This cannot be used to insert new record because the key is already there in the database. One option is to increment it in your code but I strongly **disagree** with incrementing the id in code, as it leads to lot of problems.

Comment: @bansi, i agree with you, autoincrement is the safest way, but i need to get back the generated key back to my code, i have searched a lot for jdbctemplate batch insert, but it doesnt support

Answer (score 0):

where have you incremented the user key ?
you get the last inserted id and use the same. Or is it getting handeled by LAT_INSERT_ID() ?
Shoudnt it be ps.setLong(1, userId+1) ?

One way to tackle this primary key problem that I have used before:

1. Create a primary key table in DB with table name and key as columns.
2. Write a stored proc that given a table name can give next available primary key (by incrementing existing key value in this table or any other algo you need)
3. You can also make that proc to pass a number to define num of keys required or you can return a range of keys (for getting multiple keys in one go)

For e.g.
for table MyTable1 initial key value is 0
when you call your proc getPrimaryKey(MyTable1) it will return you 1 and update primary key table.

Now before doing batch update, you can get the keys from this proc and set them in your query.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks..i have incremented by 1 userid+1, still getting same issue